# Need of admin for the first time in Blockchain?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, ibm-blockchain

whenever I look for a new blockchain project it is asked to make an admin first before adding any other members. And also whenever I instantiate a new build I have to create an admin. Why is it required? Why can't I directly create members and start my nodes?

Answer (score 1):

HF is an permissioned network, the only Admin has permission to install query and upgrade the chain code ,similarly every member  have to register himself with admin as know user inside fabric before doing any transaction. it is predefined in architecture.

Comment: u mean to say the new member needs a prior reference of admin to enter into the chain.